# How to filter input fields using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to filter input fields with numbers 1 to 4, and character "/". Here is what I have tried:

HTML:

```
<input id='scc' type='text' name='secc3' maxlength='4' onkeypress='return isNumber(event)' placeholder='Security code' required>
```

JavaScript:

```
function isNumber(evt) {
    var key = evt.key;
    if (key != 1 || key != 2 || key != 3 || key != 4) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: share sample input field

Comment: what did you try to code yourself? SO expects the OP to make atleased an attempt in coding the question yourself, with any problems we are here to help

Comment: html `<input id='scc' type='text' name='secc3' maxlength='4' onkeypress='return isNumber(event)' placeholder='Security code' required>`

Comment: javascript `function isNumber(evt) {
            var key = evt.key;
            if (key != 1 || key != 2 || key != 3 || key != 4) return false;
            return true;
        }`

Comment: @aderamdani Please update your question instead of posting your code in the comments or as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function isValid(event) {
  //this array contains the key codes for every valid character
  //other codes can be found here: https://keycode.info/
  const validChars = ["Digit1", "Digit2", "Digit3", "Digit4", "Numpad1", "Numpad2", "Numpad3", "Numpad4", "Slash"];

  return validChars.includes(event.code);
}
```

```html
<input id='scc' type='text' name='secc3' maxlength='4' onkeypress='return isValid(event)' placeholder='Security code' required>
```